How would I find the electric field inside a changing $B$ field solenoid?

While I'm used to the notion of an electric field solenoid, and the equation to get the average $B$ field enclosed within such.
$$
N\frac{\mu 
I}{\ell}
$$
how would I go about finding the electric field within a solenoid of a changing $B$ field?

since $\mathrm{curl} H = \epsilon_0 \dot E$ and you know $H(r, t),$ integrate wrt time: $E = \epsilon_0^{-1}\int_0^t \mathrm{curl} H(r,t')dt'$.

Are the dB/dt and E directions in your diagram correct? I suppose the E direction is poloidal. And I also suppose that B is confined within the solenoid, but E is non-zero even outside the solenoid.

The analytic closed form of a donut-shaped solenoid is interesting, but it is much harder for me to derive.
Instead, straight solenoid is discussed here. I hope this is a hint to investigate the donut shaped solenoid.
